# How to define new topic in UWSIM?

Tags: ros, uwsim

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I want to add a topic through which two vehicles can communicate with each other. Currently, the vehicles communicate to ROS and vice-versa. I want the vehicles to communicate with each other. I tried to create my own example code and put it along other examples present, but I was not able to compile it. I just want to pass timestamp from one vehicle to another. Can someone please tell me where should I start? I saw timestamp information is already included in standard message header. But I don’t know where to define my topic. Should it be in RosInterface.cpp? And how do I add my own cpp code for testing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207073/how-to-define-new-topic-in-uwsim?/) by [User_810](https://answers.ros.org/users/21697/user_810/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2015-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS is designed so that communication between nodes, regardless of where they are running, happens through the ROS master.

I'm not familiar with UWSIM, but if it's a sim that just has ROS plugins the following architecture is pretty standard:
You can write your nodes so that each robot has a [publisher and subscriber](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29).

When you initialize a publisher or subscriber with a topic:

```
ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);
```

That topic is created and the ROS master handles all communication to it. In this case the topic is called `chatter`. Aside from writing the publisher/subscriber nodes there are no additional steps to take when you want a topic created.

So, for each simulated robot you would have a node that handles outbound communication through a publisher and inbound through a subscriber. If your robots are called rob_one and rob_two, then their publishers can publish on topics: `rob_one_timestamp` and `rob_two_timestamp`, respectively. Then rob_one's subscriber can subscribe to `rob_two_timestamp` and vice versa.

It's a bit tough without seeing some of your code, and your CMakeLists.txt to understand why it isn't compiling.

---

Originally posted by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) with karma: 593 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

as aak21566 said, you just need to create a publisher and subscriber between the two robots. You don't need to modify UWSim at all, as UWSim uses ROS as middleware to publish sensor readings and subscribe to orders. So I guess what you need is to create your own ROS nodes for each vehicle which can communicate with UWSim  and between them.

---

Originally posted by [Javier Perez](https://answers.ros.org/users/3430/javier-perez/) with karma: 486 on 2015-04-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2